# Active Record Query Collecting 2 attributes

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Whats the best way to query/collect 2 or 3 attributes per object when using rails/active record?

An example would be if I wanted to query my user table and grab all of the user ids and emails for a certain type of user.

If I only wanted to get the user ids I would do

```
User.where(:condition => nil).collect {|u| u.id}
```

but what if I want the id and email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect the `id` and `email` in an array:

```
User.where(:condition => nil).collect {|u| [u.id, u.email]}
```

Or if you wanted a hash in the form `{:id => :email}`:

```
User.where(:conditions => nil).inject({}) {|m, u| m[u.id] = u.email; m}
```

You can make this slightly more efficient if you tell the database to only get the fields that you will be needing by using `select`:

```
User.where(:conditions => nil).select([:id, :email]).
     collect {|u| [u.id, u.email]}
```